# How can I migrate Odoo old binary field to new odoo versions with attachment=True?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9

I have an old odoo version(v6) and I am migrating it to odoo-10, Issue I am facing is for binary field data migration. As odoo-10 has attribute "attachment=True", but for older versions this was not there. 
So can I get little idea from stack community, about how can I achieve my task and how can I migrate that postgres table to odoo-10 compatible data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Just migrate the data as is, let them exist in database. I had to write a module to achieve the same requirement, because a customer had attachments in database instead of using attachments.

The following code works, it's not offically in my company's apps in Odoo's App Store, but eventually will find its way into it ;-)

```py
from odoo import api, models, exceptions
from odoo.osv import expression


class IrAttachment(models.Model):
    """ Attachment Extensions"""

    _inherit = 'ir.attachment'

    @api.model
    def _relocate_binary_data(
            self, model=None, fields=None, domain=None, limit=0):
        """ Relocates binary data into attachments. This method
            has no functionality to reverse the process.

            Use this to change binary fields to attachment usage,
            which is done by using the parameter attachment=True

            @param model: Model Name (required)
            @param fields: List of binary field names (required)
            @param domain: optional search domain to filter treated records
                (default: []==no filter)
            @param limit: optional filter limit (default: 0==unlimited)"""
        if not model or not fields:
            raise exceptions.Warning(
                "model and fields are required parameters")
        # only touch records with binary data in one of the provided fields
        default_domain = [[(f, '!=', False)] for f in fields]
        default_domain = expression.OR(default_domain)
        domain = expression.AND([domain, default_domain])
        records = self.env[model].with_context(active_test=False).search(
            domain, limit=limit)
        # relocate the binary data to attachments
        for record in records:
            for field in fields:
                # search for existing attachments (for re-runs)
                attachment = records.env['ir.attachment'].sudo().search([
                    ('res_model', '=', record._name),
                    ('res_field', '=', field),
                    ('res_id', '=', record.id),
                ])
                # write the binary value to existing attachment or create one
                if attachment:
                    attachment.write({'datas': getattr(record, field)})
                else:
                    self.env['ir.attachment'].create({
                        'name': record.name,
                        'res_model': record._name,
                        'res_field': field,
                        'res_id': record.id,
                        'type': 'binary',
                        'datas': getattr(record, field)
                    })
        # empty the database binary data
        records.write({f: None for f in fields})
```

You have to write a `ir.cron` or a `ir.actions.server` to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the read function for the Binary class (`<path_to_v12>/odoo/fields.py lines 1786-1800`, cited below) you'll notice that it searches `ir.attachment` for records having the right model, field and id.

```
def read(self, records):
    # values are stored in attachments, retrieve them
    assert self.attachment
    domain = [
        ('res_model', '=', records._name),
        ('res_field', '=', self.name),
        ('res_id', 'in', records.ids),
    ]
    # Note: the 'bin_size' flag is handled by the field 'datas' itself
    data = {att.res_id: att.datas
            for att in records.env['ir.attachment'].sudo().search(domain)}
    cache = records.env.cache
    for record in records:
        cache.set(record, self, data.get(record.id, False))
```

So, my educated guess is that you can update your 'ir_attachment' records and adding `res_model` (note that this is a string!), `res_field` (also a string) and `res_id` (this is the integer saved on the `id` field of the referring record).

Comment: He is coming from OpenERP 6 without having `ir.attachment` records. The binary data was saved as bytea directly in the database in those medieval days back then. So sorry, but this is not the right answer, but a good hint how Odoo is reading binary fields with `attachment=True`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have barely touched a v6. @CZoellner thanks for the advice! Given that this answer is not correct, should I remove it?

Comment: No let it stay.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use XMLRPC to read the data from SRC and write the data in DEST. Which would take care of your issue. It would read the data from the binary field while creating attachment it would store in the filesystem.